# In Google Sheet, add 1 to value of a cell and save the result as a PDF in Google Drive, add 1 again and save a PDF again,

Tags: google-apps-script

First of all, I'm not a programmer so this might be an easy one for some of you...

I'm making a Google Sheet for grading children in Primary school. I made the spreadsheet like that, that if you enter the class number of a student in cell H3, the grades of that student appear on the sheet. So far so good.

Now what I'm trying to do, is write a script that adds 1 to the value of cell H3 and then saves a PDF in the Google Drive of the teacher.

For now, I have a "script" that I copied and pasted from the web... I found that I needed to hide all sheets that I don't want on the PDF. (So that's what the "ShowOneSheet" and "ShowAllSheets" function is about.)

Probably, the code is very inefficient, I have no clue. :)

For now, I have a menu in which you can do everything manually. (go to next student, save in pdf to drive, go to next student, save in pdf in drive, ...)

**I want the script to do this as many times as there are students. That way, teachers can get a report for all students in their google drive with only one click.**

**I also don't know how to make a folder/pdf that has a specified name. (for now, it saves both folder and pdf as "undefined".)**

Any help would be much appreciated! I'm a dummy, but eager to learn.

```
function onOpen() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
ui.createMenu('Reports')
  .addItem('Show only grades sheet', 'showOneSheet')
  .addItem('Go to next report', 'nextclassnr')
  .addItem('Save this report in PDF in Drive', 'createPdf')
  .addItem('Show all sheets', 'showAllSheets')
  .addToUi();
}
function showOneSheet(SheetToShow) {
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
for(var i in sheets){
if (sheets[i].getName()==SheetToShow){
  sheets[i].showSheet();
}
else {
  sheets[i].hideSheet();
}
}
}




function nextclassnr() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[3];
//Set variables and add one to the "classnumber"
var classnrR= sheet.getRange("H3");

var classnr = classnrR.getValue();
var nextclassnr = 1 + classnr;

classnrR.setValue(nextclassnr);


}



 //PDF in folder "undefined" named "undefined" :(

  function createPdf(saveToFolder, fileName){

 var ssa = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var pdf = ssa.getAs("application/pdf"); 
 try {
  var folder = DocsList.getFolder(saveToFolder);
 }
 //Create Folder if not exists
  catch(error){
  folder = DocsList.createFolder(saveToFolder);
  }
 var file = folder.createFile(pdf);
 file.rename(fileName);

 return file;
 }


// make sheets visible

function showAllSheets() {
var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
for(var i in sheets){
  sheets[i].showSheet();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here you can find the result of the spreadsheet with the code attached.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DzpdBt-pKmMLPITKvgnyPLODUfg0eeA4hU5Qy6e6V7I/edit?usp=sharing) I used the code Andrew Roberts gave me and had to change some pieces and bits.

Here you can also find the code I used in the script:

```
//EVENT HANDLERS
//------------------



// MAKE MENU
//------------
function onOpen() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
ui.createMenu('Reports')
 // .addItem('Werkbladen verbergen', 'showOneSheet')
 //  .addItem('Alle werkbladen tonen', 'showAllSheets')    
  .addItem('Show next report', 'nextClassNumber')
  .addItem('Show report of number...', 'showReportClassNumber')
  .addSeparator()
      .addSubMenu(ui.createMenu('Process reports')
             .addItem('Process all reports', 'processAllStudents')
             .addItem('Process report of number...', 'processOneStudent')  
                  )
        .addToUi();
 } 





// SHOW ONLY ONE SHEET 
//------------------------
function showOneSheet() {
  var SheetToShow = ("RAPPORT")
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for(var i in sheets){
    if (sheets[i].getName()==SheetToShow){
      sheets[i].showSheet();
    }
    else {
      sheets[i].hideSheet();
    }
  }}




// SHOW REPORT OF NUMBER...
//-------------------
function showReportClassNumber() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[4];
  //Set variables and add one to the "classNumber"
  var classNumberRange = sheet.getRange("classnumber"); 
  var classNumber = Browser.inputBox("Class number","What is the number of the student you would         like to see?",Browser.Buttons.OK);
  classNumberRange.setValue(classNumber);

}



    // NEXT CLASSNUMBER
    //-------------------
function nextClassNumber() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheets()[4];
  //Set variables and add one to the "classNumber"
  var classNumberRange = sheet.getRange("I4"); 
  var classNumber = classNumberRange.getValue();
  var nextClassNumber = classNumber + 1;

classNumberRange.setValue(nextClassNumber);

}






// EXPORT CURRENT REPORT TO PDF
//----------------------------------
  function createPdf(classnrR,sheet){
 // saveToFolder, fileName  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[4];
  var ssa = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pdf = ssa.getAs("application/pdf"); 
  var folders;
  var nextFolder;
  var foundFolder = false;
  var classNumber = sheet.getRange("classnumber").getValue();

  var CLASS_NAME_RANGE = sheet.getRange("klas")
  var CLASS_NAME = CLASS_NAME_RANGE.getValue();
  var FOLDER_NAME = 'Rapporten ' + CLASS_NAME;  

  var FILE_NAME = "Rapport "+classNumber+".pdf";

  // DocList is deprecated
  folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(FOLDER_NAME);

  // See if we already have the folder
  while (folders.hasNext()) {

    if (!foundFolder) {
      folders.next().createFile(pdf).setName(FILE_NAME);
      foundFolder = true;  
    } else {

      throw new Error('There are multiple folders with the name ' + FOLDER_NAME + '. Remove or rename them, please.');
    }  
  }

  if (!foundFolder) {

    // No folder already so create it



    DriveApp
  .createFolder(FOLDER_NAME)
  .createFile(pdf)
  .setName(FILE_NAME);
  }
}







    // SHOW ALL SHEETS
    //------------------------

function showAllSheets() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for(var i in sheets){
      sheets[i].showSheet();
  }
}


// PROCESS ONE STUDENT
//-------------------------

function processOneStudent(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[4];
  var classNumberRange= sheet.getRange("classnumber");

     showOneSheet();

  var classNumber = Browser.inputBox("Class number","What class number would you like to process the report of?",Browser.Buttons.OK);
  classNumberRange.setValue(classNumber);

     createPdf();
     showAllSheets();
} 





// PROCESS ALL STUDENTS
//----------------------------

function processAllStudents(){
 //SHOW MESSAGE
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast('Find a folder in your Google Drive named RAPPORTEN and your class name.', 'Processing... Be patient', 15);
  //Hide all sheets
  showOneSheet()
    //Go to the first report

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[4];
  var aantalleerlingen = sheet.getRange("P4").getValue();
  var classNumberRange= sheet.getRange("I4");

  classNumberRange.setValue("0");

  // Go thrue all reports
  for (i = 0 ;i <= aantalleerlingen; i++){
 nextClassNumber();
 createPdf();
  }

  // Show all sheets
showAllSheets();

    //Set classnumber back to "1"
    classNumberRange.setValue("1");


   }
```

Answer (score 2):

I've reworked your code a bit and this does what I think you wanted it to do, without doing the 'running it as many times as there are students'. If you could explain that a bit more, or I've [created a sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Oa2xTc1K7qMzZDxsDuWLax9Q8EpW3r8Un_eUUJ-vTA8/edit?usp=sharing) you can update to show your situation, and this also has this script attached.

```
// Define your names here

var FOLDER_NAME = 'PDFPlus1';
var FILE_NAME = FOLDER_NAME + ' - Student Grades - Class ';

// Event handlers
// --------------

function onOpen() {

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  ui.createMenu('Reports')
    .addItem('Show only grades sheet', 'showGradesSheet')
    .addItem('Go to next report', 'nextClassNumber')
    .addItem('Save this report in PDF in Drive', 'createPdf')
    .addItem('Show all sheets', 'showAllSheets')
    .addItem('Create a report for each student', 'processAllStudents')        
    .addToUi();
}

function showGradesSheet() {

  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

  // Grades sheet (?)
  var SheetToShow = sheets[3];

  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {

    if (sheets[i] === SheetToShow) {

      sheets[i].showSheet(); 

    } else {

      sheets[i].hideSheet();
    }
  }
}

function nextClassNumber() {

  var classNumberRange = getClassNumberRange_();
  var classNumber = classNumberRange.getValue();
  classNumber++;
  classNumberRange.setValue(classNumber);
}

function createPdf(){

  // saveToFolder, fileName  

  var ssa = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var pdf = ssa.getAs("application/pdf"); 
  var folders;
  var nextFolder;
  var foundFolder = false;
  var classNumber = getClassNumberRange_().getValue();

  // DocList is deprecated
  folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(FOLDER_NAME);

  // See if we already have the folder
  while (folders.hasNext()) {

    if (!foundFolder) {

      folders.next().createFile(pdf).setName(FILE_NAME + classNumber);
      foundFolder = true;  

    } else {

      throw new Error('multiple folders named ' + FOLDER_NAME);
    }  
  }

  if (!foundFolder) {

    // No folder already so create it
    DriveApp
      .createFolder(FOLDER_NAME)
      .createFile(pdf)
      .setName(FILE_NAME + classNumber);
  }
}

// Make sheets visible

function showAllSheets() {

  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();

  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {

    sheets[i].showSheet();
  }
}

function processAllStudents() {

  // Could easily call the other event handlers to automate the 
  // PDF creation, just need to call createPDF() with a student ID number
  // rather than pulling it from the sheet

  // for all students {
  //   createPDF(studentIdNumber);
  // }

}    

// Local functions
// ---------------

function getClassNumberRange_() {

  return classNumberRange = SpreadsheetApp
    .getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheets()[3]
    .getRange("H3");
}
```

Comment: Hi, In Belgium we use scores with numbers to give student grades... (different system) I filled out the google sheet with some dummy information, so you can see what I'm trying to do here. Every student gets a "personalised" print of sheet "Grades". So what I want to do is that the script runs "add 1 to change classnumber" AND "save PDF in Google Drive" For now, you already helped me out a lot. I think I can manage the rest on my own. I'll post a link to the sheet and the code so you can see the "end result" of my little project or give some advice if you feel that is needed. Thanks a lot!